# Visual studio и OpenServer

Tags: c#, mysql, openserver

У меня есть база данных mysql, создал через phpmyadmin, встроенный в openserver.
То есть я хочу подключить её к проекту Visual Studio, как будто она находится на сервере. Возможно ли это сделать без дополнительной установки mysql connector на компьютер? Если да то как?

Comment: а обычно подключать со студии не получается? коннектор должен ставиться автоматом при установке сервера. Без него вроде бы не работает, но это не точно (я всегда его ставил)

Comment: со студией обычно юзают IIS

Comment: Не получится. Mysql Connector это драйвер обеспечивающий подключение. Без него только написать свой драйвер, но это совсем плохой вариант.

Comment: Кстати, а почему не хотите его ставить?

Comment: *хочу подключить её к проекту Visual Studio, как будто она находится на сервере* Эммм... а сейчас оно где? в ящике стола, что ли? на сервере и есть (даже если клиент и сервер - в рамках одного инстанса ОС).